# Guardar valor en un campo dependiendo del valor de otro campo en Rest Framework

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Buenos días

Estoy tratando de cambiar lo que tengo hecho en forms a serializers y me encuentro con que con forms, depeniendo de una fecha que se introduce, me calcula otra fecha para otro campo.

He visto la que el SerializedMethodField hace lo que necesito pero no sirve para guardar datos, ¿que otras opciones tengo?

```
FechaValidoHasta = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_FechaValidoHasta(self, obj):
        seisMeses = relativedelta(months=6)
        return obj.FechaValidoDesde+seisMeses
```

Parece que podría ser usando Custom Fields, pero no veo la forma de hacer referencia al otro campo a la hora de calcular la fecha.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigarlo, no veo claro que Rest Framework tenga implementado esto en la parte relacionada con los serializers. Si estoy equivocado y si que lo incluye, por favor aportar un respuesta nueva. Para solucionarlo de otro modo, lo que he hecho es sobreescribir los metodos perform_update y perform_create en el ModelViewSet, en el fichero views.py, sacando el valor del otro campo desde self.resquest.POST['FechaValidoDesde'] y asi poder calcular el valor de FechaValidoHasta. En el fichero serializers.py, este caso, no hace falta indicar nada especial.

```
#views.py

class CertificadoBackendListAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Certificado.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CertificadoEditSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        seisMeses = relativedelta(months=6)
        Fecha=datetime.strptime(self.request.POST['FechaValidoDesde'],'%Y-%m-%d')+seisMeses 
        serializer.save(FechaValidoHasta=datetime.date(Fecha))

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        seisMeses = relativedelta(months=6)
        Fecha=datetime.strptime(self.request.POST['FechaValidoDesde'],'%Y-%m-%d')+seisMeses 
        serializer.save(FechaValidoHasta=datetime.date(Fecha))
```